# mock external system working through websphere mq

Tags: mocking, ibm-mq, messagebroker

I'm developing integration solution with *message broker*. Solution communicates with the back-end system using *websphere mq*. During development process I don't have an access to the real back-end service so I have to mock it somehow. Mock implementation has to read message from queue, perform simple transformation, and put message back to queue. To achieve that, I've considered creating separate message flow but what I'm actually looking for is ready-made solution which I could leverage these tasks to.

Does anybody know any tool that might be useful for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about setting up your own QMgr?  Or even your own broker and QMgr?  According to the license terms of recent versions of WebSphere Message Broker, anyone with a single paid license is entitled to install any or all of the broker components on developer desktops (Windows and Linux). The Infocetner [*License Requirements*](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bh25920_.htm) topic states:

> Your license also covers use of the product for development and unit
>   test purposes. All developers in your organization, who are working on
>   resources and applications for WebSphere Message Broker, can install
>   one copy of all components on their computer. They can create and
>   configure a broker environment without any functional or resource
>   restrictions. Installation of the WebSphere Message Broker Toolkit
>   limits this use to Windows, Linux on x86, and Linux on x86-64
>   computers. The unit test environment is limited to these three
>   platforms even if you have purchased a license for WebSphere Message
>   Broker for z/OS.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but I want to have some reusable component that would be loosely coupled to the broker itself, so it can be used as a stub in similar cases with a few changes. There are tools allowing mocking SOAP-services, and I just was wondering if there are something similar for mocking MQ-apps.

Comment: I don't know of any projects to do this. It would have to understand the WMQ channel protocols and these are not published by IBM. It would also need to handle the range of API calls and their options, transactions, etc. On the other hand, there's no cost to spin up additional QMgrs on a single server, or for a company with WMB to put WMQ on the desktops of all the developers. Most shops just dedicate another QMgr to Dev, even if its on the same host as integration test or QA.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that allow for mocking or simulating systems communicating via IBM Websphere MQ.

You can use for example [Traffic Parrot](http://trafficparrot.com/documentation/3.10.x/ibmmq.html). It will read a message from a request queue, do the transformations (using its [extensions](http://trafficparrot.com/documentation/3.10.x/extensions.html#extract-data)) and put a response message on a response queue. Have a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHREpYQ-vvM) that demonstrates how to do it.

Have a look at other [API simulation tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools), just make sure you choose one that supports IBM MQ.